# Generic abstract argument for method C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code example. And I don't get why it does not compile. It does not allow to convert from `D` to `A<B>`.

`D` inherits `A<C>`. `C` inherits `B`, so that would mean I should be able to pass `D` into a `A<B>` method argument right? I'm probably missing something obvious here.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var d = new D();
        Foo(d);  //Cannot convert D to A<B>

    }

    private void Foo(A<B> bar)
    {

    }   
}

public abstract class A<TypeB> where TypeB : B
{
     public abstract List<TypeB> list { get; set; } 
}

public abstract class B
{
}

public class C : B
{

}

public class D : A<C>
{
     public override List<C> list { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Because `D` doesn't inherit from `A<B>`. If you can write `A<B> ab = new D();` then this code will work and you can't do that.

Answer (score 9):

This question has been asked hundreds of times on this site.

Suppose you have a bowl of fruit.  Is it a bowl of apples?  An apple is a fruit, so why is a bowl of fruit not a bowl of apples?  Obviously because a bowl of fruit could already contain a banana, and so is not a bowl of apples.

Suppose you have a bowl of apples. Is it a bowl of fruit?  You want to say "an apple is a fruit, therefore a bowl of apples is a bowl of fruit".  But this is wrong. **A bowl of fruit is something you can put a banana into**, and since there is an operation you can perform on a bowl of fruit that you cannot perform on a bowl of apples, a bowl of apples cannot be used in a context where a bowl of fruit is expected.

The technical name for the kind of conversion you want is a "generic covariant conversion".  C# supports generic covariant conversions in only a few specific cases:

- The "outer" type must be an interface or delegate, for example, `IEnumerable<T>`.
- The "inner" type must be a reference type, like string, not a value type, like int.
- The "outer" type must be marked as safe for covariance; this is checked by the compiler.

You can use an `IEnumerable<Apple>` in a context where `IEnumerable<Fruit>` is expected because *there is no way to put a banana into an `IEnumerable<Fruit>`*.  But you cannot use your class `A<Apple>` as an `A<Fruit>` because the compiler is not convinced that you have prevented all possibility of another type Banana that extends Fruit being used in a method that can only accept an Apple.

Do a search on this site for "covariance and contravariance" and you will find plenty of questions about this.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Very clear answer. Seems I was indeed missing something obvious.

Comment: @FreekvanZee: I wouldn't say it is obvious. This is a VERY frequently asked question; if it were obvious why it didn't work, it wouldn't be so frequently asked. Also, *contravariance* is very unobvious to many people. That is: I have an `IComparer<Animal>` that can compare any two animals, so I can use it as an `IComparer<Tiger>` to compare two tigers. Notice how the direction of convertibility is *backwards* compared to `IEnumerabl<Fruit>` and `IEnumerable<Apple>`, hence *contra*variant.